# Splitting unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, split

Sorry, I know there are a million similar questions, but I'm still stumped.

I have something that returns: `[u'adidas\nReebok']`

I am trying to split it so that I have an iterable list = `['adidas', 'Reebok']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `split()` on the unicode string:

```
>>> u'adidas\nReebok'.split()
[u'adidas', u'Reebok']
```

If the string is contained within a list:

```
>>> l = [u'adidas\nReebok']
>>> manufacturers = l[0].split()
>>> manufacturers
[u'adidas', u'Reebok']
>>> for x in manufacturers:
...     print x
... 
adidas
Reebok
```

Comment: Maybe I'm at the height of my idiocy tonight. That works, but then when I `for x in manufacturers: print x` I just get `[u'adidas', u'Reebok']` again.

Comment: Thank you for humoring my dumb question with an answer instead of downvoting it.